# android notification is not taking me to the activity when the app is hidden but works when the app is open

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm unable to go the activity(dosomething.class) when the app is not open but it works when the app's mainactivity.class is open. How can I go to the doactivty.class when the app is running in the background or hidden?

Currently, it takes me the mainactivity.class when I click on the notification also when the mainactivity.class is not shown then the notification sound is not played. I've tried many ways to get it to work but currently nothing is working.

Code:

Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />



<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.example.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.example.example.Firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.example.example.Firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>




 <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name="com.example.example.dosomething"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:label="example"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity


            </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried this :

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, dosomething.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)//
                    .setContentTitle("title")//
                    .setContentText("text")//
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("title"))//
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)//
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)//
                    .setTicker("testapp")//
                    .build();

            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

and this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dosomething.class);
            intent.putExtra("data", tasks);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setContentText("text")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setLights(Color.parseColor("#0086dd"), 2000, 2000);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(dosomething.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

//            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


            PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder
                    .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                            | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

and this :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"channelid");

            //Create the intent that’ll fire when the user taps the notification//

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dosomething.class);
            intent.putExtra("data", tasks);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            mBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: What type of FCM are you sending `Data` only or `Notification` ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that is actually the error here, but make sure to use RequestCodes different from 0 with PendingIntent.

Comment: @Barns I'm sending title,message and key,value pairs in data.